# GCC instruction relative addressing

Tags: gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler

The following code worked just fine in gcc6.2:

```
int main(){
long x, y = 0;

__asm__ (
    ".data\n\t"
    "var_0: .byte 2\n\t"

    ".text\n\t"
    "xor %%eax, %%eax\n\t"

    "leaq var_0(%%rax), %%rbx\n\t"
    "movb var_0(%%rax), %%al\n\t"

    "movq %%rax, %0\n\t"
    "movq %%rbx, %1\n\t"

    :"=m" (x), "=m" (y)
    :
    :"%rax", "%rbx"
    );

printf("%x %x\n",x, y);

}
```

Sample output of this is `2 601031`. This syntax suggests to me that gcc (or gas I suppose) uses instruction relative addressing. If I replace the above lines with

```
"leaq var_0(%%rip), %%rbx\n\t"
"movb var_0(%%rip), %%al\n\t"
```

then the output is again `2 601031` (EDIT: previous statement was incorrect as I had the output of slightly different code). I don't know where this is documented but it's great. However, when I upgraded to gcc6.3, the RIP relative addressing version still works fine but the instruction relative version produces the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc2E9Upc.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
```

even if I recompile with `gcc -fPIC`. Could someone tell me what's going on between the two versions of gcc? Are there any changes I need to be aware of? Flags that I need to be using?

EDIT 2: PLaying around with `objdump` has made it clear to me that the title is nonsense. Gcc6.2 simply uses the translated address of `var_0` in the executable. I would like to know why this doesn't work with gcc4.3 while I apologize for the hastily written title.

Comment: Try compiling with `-fno-pie`.

Comment: @Ross Ridge, same issue

Comment: Is this a newer version of Debian or Ubuntu (or a newer version of a debian/ubuntu based system)?

Comment: Post your complete command that you used.

Comment: @Jester, it is `gcc test.c -fno-pie -fPIC`

Comment: @MichaelPetch, it is Debian unstable ('Sid').

Comment: What if you build it with `-static`

Comment: @MichaelPetch, worked like a charm! Could you post an answer (hopefully with an explanation :-)) so I can accept it and consider this problem answered?

Comment: @MichaelPetch, one more thing, why is the static linking working but the dynamic one failing in gcc6.3? Is it a bug? Statically linking make a much bigger executive which is not always preferable.

Comment: I didn't provide it as answer, just a comment with reason. The difference on newer Ubuntus and Debian is that the compiler uses a different set of implicit options when building executables. One of those is that by default everything is built as either position independent code and position independent executables when the target is 64-bit. In older versions of these distros executables were not built as position independent. I don't consider `-static` a solution, just wanted to know if it built properly with it.

Comment: I consider RIP relative addressing the better way of doing it.

Comment: Do you know why the -fPIC option does not work? Another thing: I am under the understanding that RIP relative addressing doesn't allow for a register offset and scaling and I feel that's a limitation. Is there a workaround for those cases?

Comment: Nothing stops you from doing something like `leaq var_0(%%rip), %%rbx` and then use RBX as a base for a further move instruction like `movb (%%rbx), %%al`  Of course now `(%%rbx)` can be any of the addressing modes including scaling etc.If _RDX_ were an index (like walking an array) you could do something like `movb (%%rbx,%%rdx,1), %%al`

Comment: @Ivan The `-fPIC` option doesn't work because it only affects the code GCC generates, not the code you put in `asm` statements. Try `gcc -fno-pie test.c`